# Cannot convert 'double' to 'float' but I am not using double

Tags: c#, floating-point, double

```
class Program
    {

        static float vSphere(float radi)  
        {
            float radius = Math.Pow(radi, 3); //line 14
            float vol = (4 / 3) * 3.14 * radius;  //line 15
            return vol;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Work out the volume of sphere
            Console.WriteLine("Please specify a radius: ");
            float user_radius = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            float answer = vSphere(user_radius);
            Console.WriteLine("The sphere is: ");
            Console.WriteLine(answer);
        }

    }
```

This is the C# code to a program I am trying to write that works out the volume of a sphere.

On line 14 and 15, I am told that I cannot implicitly convert from 'double' to 'float'.  I cannot see where I am using a double, and I need to use floats because the user could enter a decimal number like 3.147.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the method signature: [Math.Pow](https://www.google.no/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=math.pow%20.net)

Comment: Function Math.Pow returns a double.

Comment: Better: Use `double` instead of `float`. `double` carries better precision. Your explanation of why you are using `float` explains why you aren't using `int`, but not why you can't use `double`.

Comment: Also, the expression `(4 / 3)` does not evaluate to what you seem to expect.

Comment: I'd advice against hard-coding the value of pi. I don't know what accuracy the Math.PI offers (a constant that is part of the Math library) but I'd suggest using it instead unless the digits after the decimal point are not that important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Line 14: [`Math.Pow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `double`
- Line 15: The `(4 / 3) * 3.14 * radius` expression is inferred to be of type `double` by the compiler by default. Use the `f` literal suffix to tell the compiler it is a float:

  ```
  float vol = (4 / 3) * 3.14f * radius;
  ```

Answer (score 4):

The `Math.Pow` method always returns a `double` value, so you would need to cast it back to `float`:

```
float radius = (float)Math.Pow(radi, 3);
```

The literal value `3.14` is a `double` value. You can use the `f` suffix to make it a `float` value:

```
float vol = (4 / 3) * 3.14f * radius;
```

Note that the expression `4 / 3` is calculated using `int` values, so the result will be `1`, not `1.333333` as you might expect. Use `float` values there too:

```
float vol = (4f / 3f) * 3.14f * radius;
```

As rbaleksandar pointed out, there is a pi constant in the `Math` class that you should use rather than writing it out. It's a `double` value though, so you would need to cast it to a `float`:

```
float vol = (4f / 3f) * (float)Math.PI * radius;
```

Comment: @rbaleksandar: That's a good point. You should put that in a comment to the question.

Comment: Dang it, I thought it was a comment to the question. XD I guess I scrolled a bit too much. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you will look into the defintion of [Math.Pow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx) then you will see that it takes two double arguments and returns a double. You need to cast it like this:

```
float radius = (float)Math.Pow(radi, 3);
```

There is no implicit conversion from double to float hence you need to cast it to float.

Similarly

```
float vol = (4.0 / 3.0) * 3.14f * radius;
```

Answer (score 0):

As Math.Pow returns a double value you should explicitly cast it to float by 
float radius = (float)Math.Pow(radi, 3);

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
   static float vSphere(float radi)  
    {
        float radius = (float)Math.Pow(radi, 3); //line 14
        float vol = (4f / 3f) * 3.14f * radius;;  //line 15
        return vol;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Math.Pow` returns a double type that you need to cast back to a float